# How to get a list of non read only files in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, read-only, dir

I need to find a way to get a list of all the Non Read Only files under a specific path on windows server 2003.

I tried the following command, but I also got all the directories which are non Read Only.

```
DIR c:\Project\Finance /A:-R /S > Open_Files_List.txt
```

Then I saw on the Web that the "D" attribute might help me, but no matter how i use it, i can't get the wanted result...

Here are the ways I tried to make it work...

```
/A:-R -D /S
/A:-RD /S
/A:-R -D /S
/A:-DR -D /S
/A:-D /S
/A:-DR /S
```

As you can guess, no success!

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

```
dir /A:-D-R /S
```

`/A:-D` specifies that you don't want directories. `-R` specifies that readonly attribute isn't present. You did try something similar. But the space between `-R` and `-D` confused the `dir` program...

Comment: What do these parameters do?

Comment: /A:-D specifies that you don't want directories. -R specifies that readonly attribute isn't present. You did try something similar. But the space between -R and -D confused the dir program.

Answer (score 2):

As you specified attributes are working same..

[image]
check this..
list of non read only files excluding directories.

```
dir /a-dr
```

[image]

your desired result can be achieved using following command:

```
dir /a-d-r
```

check this in second command result.. just add you recursive search /d after this..
hope this help you..